# Simplifying Circuits with kirchoffs rules

Tags: physics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e7P4.png)

I have spent such a long time looking at videos on simplifying circuits which I understand but even the complex ones that I am coming across seem more straight forward for finding equivalent resistances and simplifying the diagrams. Once I simplify this circuit I can calculate the currents at points A and B

If anyone could help with this it would be appreciated. Have attached an image as well.

Comment: There is a stackexchange for physics and one for electronics. May be worth checking out if it's your main interest. Always a chance it gets flagged as off topic if it's too applied.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no places wehre two resistors are either purely in series or in parallel, "simplifying" this circuit is a dead end -- it is already as simple as any equivalent circuit can be.

Fortunately, calculating the currents and voltages is not too hard.  There are only three regions that could have different vlotages:  The one containing point A,
the one containing point B, and the one containing the lower left hand corner of your diagram, which I will call point C.  Since the zero-point of voltage is arbitrary, let's say that point C is at $0$ volts.

Then the 6 volt battery enforces

$$V_A = V_C + 6 = 6$$

and the 12 volt battery enforces

$$V_B = V_C + 12 = 12$$

So there will be a current, across the $20\Omega$ resistor, of $(12-6)/20 = .3$ amps going counterclockwise in your diagram.

And, since $V_B = V_C + 12$, there will be a current of $12/30 = .4$ amps going from B on the left across the  $20\Omega$ resistor and toward point C.

Finally, what is the current $I$ going between the positive end of the 12-volt battery and point B?  Well, it splits up into $.3$ amps going up to go through the  $20\Omega$ resistor, $.4$ amps going left to go through the  $30\Omega$ resistor, and some mount $I$ that will remain to go down toward the right side of the $60\Omega$ resistor. But $I$ is a current across a $60\Omega$ resistor that has a voltage drop of 12V; thus $I$ is  $.2$ amps.

Now we can determine all the other currents.  For example, the current in the short stretch going up from the juncture just to the left of the $60\Omega$ resistor, going up to the juncture just to the left of the 12 volt pattery, has to be $.2$ amps from the wirer coming from its right, plus the same $.3$ amps that went through the $60\Omega$ resistor and the 6 volt battery and comes in from the left, for a total of $.5$ amps.  This, plus $.4$ amps coming from above, tells you that the current going left to right through the 12 volt battery is .9 amps.

And just as a check, the current coming to $B$ from the left is $.9$ amps,. which ultimately gets divided into $.4$ through the $30\Omega$ resistor, $.3$ through the $20\Omega$ resistor, and the remaining $.2$ heading south to go through the through the $60\Omega$ resistor.

Comment: I suspect that the "simplified" circuit diagram requested in the problem might just be asking for a diagram where it's more obvious what's in parallel and what's in series.